# Adding an object to a list before onCreate method in an Activity in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm just curious about something, so I have tried to write some code this way:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button trueButton, falseButton, nextButton;
    private ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    private int currentIndex = 0;
    private TextView questionTextView;
     questionList.add(new Question(R.string.question_australia,true));
        questionList.add(new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true));
        questionList.add(new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false));
        questionList.add(new Question(R.string.question_africa, false));
        questionList.add(new Question(R.string.question_americas, true));
        questionList.add(new Question(R.string.question_asia, true));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        trueButton = findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        falseButton = findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        nextButton = findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,R.string.correct_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0);

        trueButton.setOnClickListener((View v) ->{
            toast.show();
        });
        falseButton.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
            toast.show();
        });
    }
}
```

but there is an error which seems to happen only if I add those Question Objects before the onCreate method.

An example when the code works:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button trueButton, falseButton, nextButton;
    private ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    private int currentIndex = 0;
    private TextView questionTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        trueButton = findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        falseButton = findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        nextButton = findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,R.string.correct_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0);

        trueButton.setOnClickListener((View v) ->{
            toast.show();
        });
        falseButton.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
            toast.show();
        });
        questionList.add(new Question(R.string.question_australia,true));
        questionList.add(new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true));
        questionList.add(new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false));
        questionList.add(new Question(R.string.question_africa, false));
        questionList.add(new Question(R.string.question_americas, true));
        questionList.add(new Question(R.string.question_asia, true));
    }
}
```

Why the error is shown when I add objects to a list before the onCreate method? I really hope I get a professional answer so I will understand onCreate method better.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here:

1. You cannot execute methods directly in the class, unless you are assigning the result value to a variable (e.g. `String text = "hello".substring(3)` would work, `"hello".substring(3)` alone not.
2. The onCreate Methods is part of the Android life cycle (there are many explanations for it on StackOverflow). Basically it is called, when an activity, so an object of the class xy extends AppCompatActivity, is created and all the data from the resources is loaded. But the class object is created before the resources are loaded, so you cannot access any resources before `onCreate()`. Unlike the code executed in the static section (`static {...}`), which is called when the program starts, the onCreate method can be called multiple times (e.g. I click on the back-button [and there is no activity to go back to]. The activity is stopped but the app is not closed. When I reopen the app, it is still started, just like the programm is.

- You can do anything which is not android resource related (e.g. creating an ArrayList) before onCreate.
- Just to avoid confusion: You always need to call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` before calling `findViewById()`, because Android needs to know from which layout it should get the view, that is another topic.